# What is wrong with this replace program in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have the following code, with jQuery implemented properly (it has been tested to function):

```
var notrightfake = $("#ansbox").val();
var notright = notrightfake.replace(" ", "");
```

and `$("#ansbox")` is an `input type="text"` box. But say I typed in `He llo t his is m e`, isn't the program supposed to display `Hellothisisme`, instead of not work at all?

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WUvu5/

Thank you for your support,

Lucas Chen

Comment: please create an example at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `replace` function only replaces the first occurrence of the substring.

You have to use a regular expression to replace all occurrences:

```
var notright = notrightfake.replace(/ /g, "");
```

Comment: See here for an explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the actual replacement, you're just assigning it to a variable in your code.

```
var notrightfake = $("#ansbox").val();
$("#ansbox").val(notrightfake.replace(" ", ""));
```

**Edit:** You'll have to use that in an event ie. `keyup`

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var newValue = this.value.replace(/\s/, '');
    $(this).val(newValue);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/3YWxh/

Comment: Right. Specifically, Javascript's String#replace method returns a *new* string, it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the answer box to come up with this.

Comment: The input box is for user input, not computer data.

Answer (score 0):

try this
notrightfake.replace(/ /gi, "");

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var notrightfake = $("#ansbox").val();
var notright = notrightfake.replace(/\s+/g, "");
alert(notright);
```

or you can use some trim function:

```
function trim(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
};
function ltrim(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+/,"");
};
function rtrim(str) {
    return str.replace(/\s+$/,"");
};
```